# Hibernate JPA @Inheritance TABLE_PER_CLASS JpaRepository on Child entity union select all tables

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, table-per-class

i have the problem i have a base abstract Entity Station with Inheritance TABLE_PER_CLASS and three child Tables StationCompany StationAnalysis StationVariant

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS )
public abstract class Station {

@Entity
public class StationCompany extends Station {

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Company company;

@Entity
public class StationAnalysis extends StationCompany {

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Analysis analysis;

@Entity
public class StationVariant extends StationAnalysis {

@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
private Variant variant;

public interface IStationCompanyRepository extends JpaRepository<StationCompany, Long> {

@Service
public class StationService implements IStationService<StationCompany> {

    @Autowired
    IStationCompanyRepository stationCompanyRepository;
```

Then i search findAll on StationCompany, hibernate make a query with union select.
i will search only for the StationCompany entrys.

```
select x from ( select a from StationCompany union select b from StationVariant union select c from StationAnalysis )
```

Comment: But StationAnalysis is a StationCompany, cannot blame hibernate for that, can you?

Comment: i need this. StationAnalysis has a @ManyToOne to Company + Analysis and StationVariant to Company + Analysis + Variant Entity

Comment: Please elaborate exactly what you want

Comment: I have three Services ( StationCompanyService / StationAnalysisService / StationVariantService )
I want search / create / save on the Table. But currently only the create + save are okay, the search is on all three tables, not only on one.

    select a from StationCompany

JpaRepository loads all Table data, but i need only one Table data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem was the hibernate mapping. i think had a problem with the structure from Station to StationCompany to Station...
I solve the problem with aditional Abstract @MappedSuperclass classes.
After that the hibernate select the correct table and no more union selects.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Station {

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractStationCompany extends Station {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Company company;

@Entity
public class StationCompany extends AbstractStationCompany {

@MappedSuperclass
public class AbstractStationAnalysis extends AbstractStationCompany {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private Analysis analysis;

@Entity
public class StationAnalysis extends AbstractStationAnalysis {

@Entity
public class StationVariant extends AbstractStationAnalysis {
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont perform search all.

Create a NamedQuery on Station:

```
@NamedQuery(name="Station.findStationByType", 
            query="SELECT s FROM Station s WHERE TYPE(s) = :type")
```

Then in the main facade of your station hierarchy:

```
public class StationFacade<Station>{
  @PersistenceContext("contextName")
  private EntityManager em;

  public List<Station> findAll(Class<? extends Station> stationType){
    return em.createNamedQuery("Station.findStationByType")
             .setParameter("type", stationType.getSimpleName())
             .getResultList();
  }
}
```

Comment: sry your solution has an error, the @NamedQuery does not known the TYPE(s).

I found the solution after execute the Named Query with

    @NamedQuery(name = "StationCompany.findAll", query = "SELECT s FROM StationCompany s")

this query also make a union select. in next post is the answer ( i cannot post the answer )

Comment: the problem was the hibernate mapping. i think had a problem with the structure from Station to StationCompany to Station...
I solve the problem with aditional Abstract @MappedSuperclass classes.

    (at)MappedSuperclass
    (at)Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
    public abstract class Station {

    (at)MappedSuperclass
    public abstract class AbstractStationCompany extends Station {
        (at)ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        (at)Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
        private Company company;

Comment: (at)Entity
    public class StationCompany extends AbstractStationCompany {

    (at)MappedSuperclass
    public class AbstractStationAnalysis extends AbstractStationCompany {
        (at)ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        (at)Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
        private Analysis analysis;

    (at)Entity
    public class StationAnalysis extends AbstractStationAnalysis {

    (at)Entity
    public class StationVariant extends AbstractStationAnalysis {